# change the background color of static control text created using CreateWindow in vc++

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++

I am working on a open source project in `VC++` and want to change the backcolor of a static control..

```
hwndRenderMessage = CreateWindow(TEXT("STATIC"), Str("MainWindow.BeginMessage"),
    WS_CHILDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE|WS_CLIPSIBLINGS|SS_CENTER,
    0, 0, 0, 0, hwndRenderFrame, NULL, hinstMain, NULL);

SendMessage(hwndRenderMessage, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), TRUE);
```

and the parent control of this control is

```
 hwndRenderFrame = CreateWindow(OBS_RENDERFRAME_CLASS, NULL,
    WS_CHILDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPCHILDREN,
    0, 0, 0, 0,
    hwndMain, NULL, hinstMain, NULL);
if(!hwndRenderFrame)
    CrashError(TEXT("Could not create render frame"));
```

So how to change the Background color of Static Control..

I google it and getting tha same answer use

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0));
SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(230,230,230));
return (INT_PTR)CreateSolidBrush(RGB(230,230,230));
}
```

But there is no switch case in the file so what to do??
Acctually i worked on c# but this is the first time on vc++

[image: Button image]

Comment: That code needs to go in your window procedure. If you don't know what that is, then it's time to dig out Petzold and go back to basics.

Comment: But i dont find any window procedure in the page.

Comment: If it's "open source",could you provide a link?

Comment: Never mind. Found it. It's "OBS"? https://github.com/jp9000/OBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the OBS source code from sourceforge.

The Window Proc is OBS::RenderFrameProc located in WindowStuff.cpp

At the bottom of the proc (but before the "return"), add:

```
else if(message == WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC ) {
    // HERE YOUR CODE
}
```

EDIT: Changing Button Background

First, an advice: "don't do that". Buttons are very important and common components of the windows GUI, and their look and feel should be consistent in all applications. Users have ways to customize things for their Desktop, as a whole, and this include "accessibility" issues and behavior. Applications that want do it in their "own special way"s only bring problems.

Second, try this code for changing the "Setting..." button background to an ugly green: Add a case in the `WM_NOTIFY` message processing in OBS::OBSProc, in the switch(wParam)

```
case ID_SETTINGS:
   if(nmh.code == NM_CUSTOMDRAW)
   {
      LPNMCUSTOMDRAW  lpcd = (LPNMCUSTOMDRAW)lParam;
      if (lpcd->dwDrawStage == CDDS_PREPAINT )
      {
         SetDCBrushColor(lpcd->hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
         SelectObject(lpcd->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
         LONG lBorders = 0;
         LONG lElipse = 5;
         RoundRect(lpcd->hdc, lpcd->rc.left + lBorders, lpcd- rc.top + lBorders,
                   lpcd->rc.right - lBorders, lpcd->rc.bottom - lBorders, lElipse, lElipse);
         return CDRF_NOTIFYPOSTPAINT;
       }
    }
    break;
```

An alternative, with more standard borders:

```
         SetDCBrushColor(lpcd->hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
         SetDCPenColor(lpcd->hdc, RGB(0, 255, 0));
         SelectObject(lpcd->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_BRUSH));
         SelectObject(lpcd->hdc, GetStockObject(DC_PEN));
         LONG lBorders = 3;
```

To be complete, you may want to check the uItemState member of lpcd, for the CDIS_HOT flag, changing the color accordingly.

Comment: hello i have another question if i have to change the background of button which function i should use?

Comment: @user3012804 Alas, things get much more complicated for buttons. I will MAYBE post an update, if I find time today.

Comment: Okay.Thanks this will be really helpful.

Comment: @user3012804 Not today. Maybe tomorrow. Don't worry, I am not forgetting.

Comment: Please give me a link to a screenshot of your app, I want to have a good look at your actual buttons. Are you in a hurry?

Comment: Well, lot of works to do in "real world" for me. I will try to find some time for you, but don't expect quick answer...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put that code in a window procedure. The window procedure looks like this:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK RenderMessageWndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
        // your code goes here
        return ....
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And you need to sub-class your window so that it uses this `WndProc`. Like this:

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndRenderMessage, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LONG_PTR)RenderMessageWndProc);
```

If you don't know what a window procedure is, or what sub-classing is, then you really need to step back and learn some basics. For instance, Petzold's classic book Programming Windows is still an excellent starting point.

Comment: This project have the procedure
  static LRESULT CALLBACK RenderFrameProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);  but it is define in header file.

Comment: @user3012804 I believe that I have answered the question that you asked. I suspect that you don't have a sound enough grounding in both C++ and Win32 to be able to do this development. In my view you need to heed the advice in the final paragraph of my answer.

Comment: So did I need to overwrite this procedure in .cpp file